# Mock package manager in android instrumentation tests

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, functional-testing

I write instrumentation test for something like this:

```java
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> yandexApps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(yandexIntent, 0);

if (!yandexApps.isEmpty()) {
    startActivity(yandexIntent);
} else {
    Intent playMarketYandexIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    playMarketYandexIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=ru.yandex.yandexmaps"));
    startActivity(playMarketYandexIntent);
}
```

This app interacts with another application, and if app for interaction was not installed, behaviour of my app changes, so I want to do something like mocking packageManager.queryIntentActivities(yandexIntent, 0).

I’ve seen solutions for unit tests, but how about instrumentation tests? Maybe, there exist some solutions involving Espresso or UIautomator?

Comment: what do you mean by mocking if app is not installed? what does packageManager.queryIntentActivities(yandexIntent, 0) do?

Comment: packageManager.queryIntentActivities(yandexIntent, 0) - this like a search in package manager app "Yandex" by intent with predetermined uri. If no app in android package manager satisfying this intent - list yandexApps will be empty. Then if this list not empty (app installed on device) intent occurs, else play market opens for installation. So I want make test for both of this situations without installing/uninstalling app "Yandex" every test run.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find a solution since you wrote your post?

Comment: no, task actually was optional and I dropped it